# Why does my swapChildren() function only partially work?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a method for a Binary Tree (tho not a BST) that will swap all left and right children. My class, which is a Binary Tree class along with an inner class for Node is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryTree {

    private Node root;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty tree.
     */
    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a tree with one node and no children.
     * 
     * @param rootData the data for the root
     */
    public BinaryTree(Object rootData) {
        root = new Node();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.left = null;
        root.right = null;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binary tree.
     * 
     * @param rootData the data for the root
     * @param left     the left subtree
     * @param right    the right subtree
     */
    public BinaryTree(Object rootData, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
        root = new Node();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.left = left.root;
        root.right = right.root;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the height of the subtree whose root is the given node.
     * 
     * @param n a node or null
     * @return the height of the subtree, or 0 if n is null
     */
    private static int height(Node n) {
        if (n == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the height of this tree.
     * 
     * @return the height
     */
    public int height() {
        return height(root);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether this tree is empty.
     * 
     * @return true if this tree is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the data at the root of this tree.
     * 
     * @return the root data
     */
    public Object data() {
        return root.data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the left subtree of this tree.
     * 
     * @return the left child of the root
     */
    public BinaryTree left() {
        BinaryTree result = new BinaryTree();
        result.root = root.left;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the right subtree of this tree.
     * 
     * @return the right child of the root
     */
    public BinaryTree right() {
        BinaryTree result = new BinaryTree();
        result.root = root.right;
        return result;
    }

    private static int countLeaves(Node n) {
        if (n == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n.isLeaf()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return countLeaves(n.left) + countLeaves(n.right);
        }
    }

    public int countLeaves() {
        return countLeaves(root);
    }

    private static int countNodesWithOneChild(Node n) {
        if (n == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n.hasOnlyOneChild()) {
            return 1 + countNodesWithOneChild(n.left) + countNodesWithOneChild(n.right);
        } else {
            return countNodesWithOneChild(n.left) + countNodesWithOneChild(n.right);
        }
    }

    public int countNodesWithOneChild() {
        return countNodesWithOneChild(root);
    }


    **public void swapChildren() {

        for(int i = 0; i < this.height()-1; i++) {
            root.swapChildren();
            root.right.swapChildren();
            root.left.swapChildren();
            Node toBeLeft = root.right;
            Node toBeRight = root.left;
            root.right = toBeRight;
            root.left = toBeLeft;
        }
        root.swapChildren();
    }**

    class Node {
        public Object data;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public Node() {
            this.data = null;
        }

        public Node(Object data, Node left, Node right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public Node(Object data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }

        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return (this.left == null && this.right == null);
        }

        public boolean hasOnlyOneChild() {
            if (this.left != null && this.right == null)
                return true;
            else if (this.left == null && this.right != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void swapChildren() {
            Node toBeRight = left;
            Node toBeLeft = right;
            left = toBeLeft;
            right = toBeRight;
        }

    }
}
```

When I run my test program, it does seem most of the nodes have switched. However, not all of them have. My test program is in the `main(Strings[] arg)` method:

```
  BinaryTree questionTree = new BinaryTree("Is it a mammal?",
         new BinaryTree("Does it have stripes?",
            new BinaryTree("Is it a carnivore?",
               new BinaryTree("It is a tiger."),
               new BinaryTree("It is a zebra.")),
            new BinaryTree("It is a pig.")),
         new BinaryTree("Does it fly?",
            new BinaryTree("It is an eagle."),
            new BinaryTree("Does it swim?",
               new BinaryTree("It is a penguin."),
               new BinaryTree("It is an ostrich."))));

  boolean done = false;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (!done)
  {
     BinaryTree left = questionTree.left();
     BinaryTree right = questionTree.right();
     if (left.isEmpty() && right.isEmpty())
     {
        System.out.println(questionTree.data());
        done = true;
     }
     else
     {
        String response;
        do
        {
           System.out.print(questionTree.data() + " (Y/N) ");
           response = in.next().toUpperCase();
        } 
        while (!response.equals("Y") && !response.equals("N"));

        if (response.equals("Y"))
        {
           questionTree = left;         
        }
        else
        {
           questionTree = right;         
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does your outer swap method loop? Why wouldn't you just execute that code once? Shouldn't it be handled through normal recursion, just like other operations on the tree?  And why, in that method, do you both call root.swapChildren() and then also swap the root's children in that method?

Don't you just want this?:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    ...
    public void swapChildren() {
        root.swapChildren();
    }
    ....
    class Node {
        ...
        public void swapChildren() {
            if (right != null)
                right.swapChildren();
            if (left != null)
                left.swapChildren();
            Node toBeRight = left;
            Node toBeLeft = right;
            left = toBeLeft;
            right = toBeRight;
        }
        ...
    }
   ...
}
```